# Use dart polymer element in existing app

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I don't want to wait anymore and would like to use a polymer element written in dart right away.

The problem is that I want to use it in an already existing app, that's running on JavaScript.

Can I just compile my polymer elements to JavaScript, include the whole thing in my current app, and use my `<awesome-element>` tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you have to build a Dart app to use Dart Polymer elements.
You can include JavaScript in a Dart/PolymerDart application.